# UIButton in scrollView position unexpected

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I created a very simple custom class from UIView. On the top there is a UIScrollView. Inside the UIScrollView, I placed a couple of buttons. The buttons position is out of the scrollview.

Here is the code.

```
class TestView: UIView {

    var tabView: UIScrollView = UIScrollView()
    var buttons = [UIButton]()
    var tabHeight: CGFloat = 40.0
    let screenWidth: CGFloat = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width
    var titles = [String]()
    var numberOfTitles = 0

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        self.addSubview(tabView)
    }

    func createUI() {
        tabView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: tabHeight)
        tabView.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        tabView.contentSize = CGSize(width: screenWidth, height: tabHeight)

        numberOfTitles = titles.count

        for var i = 0; i < numberOfTitles; ++i {
            var button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as! UIButton
            button.frame = CGRect(x: 50.0*CGFloat(i), y: 0, width: 50.0, height: tabHeight)
            button.setTitle(titles[i], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            tabView.addSubview(button)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how it looks when I debug view Hierarchy. 
[image]

But if I just change the UIScrollView to UIView, as below,

```
var tabView: UIView = UIView()
```

Then the button locations are correct, as below.

[image]

I could not figure out why. Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is because `UIScrollView` by itself only is able to scroll a container view. What you need to do is initialize a `UIScrollView` like you did originally, but instead of adding all the components to the scrollview, create a new `UIView` called `conatinerView`, change all the `tabView` to `containerView`, then change the `required init` to:

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    self.addSubview(tabView)
    tabView.addSubview(containerView)
}
```

But make sure the frame size for `containerView` is correct and so is the origin point.

Comment: Sorry, this not the reason. I have found the problem. The view controller is embedded in the Navigation controller. And by default, "Adjust scroll view insects" was selected. If I unselect this option, the original code works.

Thank you for your help.